# EclipseLink 2.4/2.5 with JBoss EAP 6.1/6.2 persist method not making object managed

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

As per the JPA 2.0 spec, after the persist method is called, the object being persisted will become a managed entity after the call. But in my case the entity object is not becoming managed. I am calling persist method from session EJB that gets the entity manager object through injection. The entity classes are packaged in jar located in ear/lib. Any ideas what could be the root cause? Here is some additional information...

1. The object is using id with generation type of IDENTITY and the id is not updated back to entity object
2. I tried dynamic weaving as well as static weaving
3. I tried using the JBoss integration to eclipselink as per the steps provided on JBoss
4. I tried both EclipseLink 2.4.2 as well as 2.5.1
5. I confirmed that the records are correctly inserted into database tables with right order and data by enabling SQL logging
6. I confirmed that the same entity manager object is using through the entire transaction and it is transaction scoped
7. I tried both options for flushmode (auto as well as commit)
8. I am using JTDS driver and tried latest version of driver
9. I tried all combinations of packaging the entity classes and placing of persistence classes.

None of the above steps helped me with resolution.

Comment: How do you know it isn't managed?  You mentioned dat is inserted, is it from the persist call?  How are you passing the object around?  Identity will cause the id to be set only when the object is inserted, so on me.flush or when the transaction commits.

Comment: I checked em.contains after the persist method call and it returns false. I even added em.flush and resulted in same. Also id is not available even after the transaction is committed (I made sure from the logs the trans is committed).

Comment: Check the EntityManager class instance that is injected.  You might try calling getDelegate on it to get the eclipselink em instance underneath and check that the instance is the same through the entire transaction.  If it is changing, it is a problem with the transaction configuration within jboss

Comment: From the logs I checked that the same em is reused. It clearly logs the fact that the same em is reused. Do you still need me to use getDelegate?

Comment: What database are you using?  Have you tried different drivers?

Comment: Using SQL Server. I tried old and new version of jtds driver. This was working fine with toplink essentials.

Comment: Turn on logging then and see what platform is being used - it should be logged when the context first logs into the database.  You may need to specify the target database if it isn't auto detecting the correct platform: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm

Comment: I see that SQLServerPlatform is used from the logs. I also tried specifying the target database and still no luck.

Comment: I did more debugging with toplink essentials (on glassfish) and I found that even in toplink the entity is not turned to managed object after the persist call. What is different from eclipselink is that after the control comes back to frontend, the id attribute is populated, whereas in case of eclipselink it is not. May be I should change my question, because what I really need is the id (I do not mind even if the object is not managed after the persist call).